# Prepare a timeline to one audio track with multiple cameras and multiple clips per camera

Tags: premiere, premiere-pro

I have a recording of a full musical theatre show with several cameras. However, the only full-length track I have is the audio. The cameras do not have ongoing tracks but separate clips with pauses inbetween. If manually arranged in Premiere, it could look like this mockup:

[image]

As there are nine cameras with sometimes a lot of clips (not just four or five), it would be extremely time-consuming to manually synchronize audio and video. However, I did not find a way to synchronize them with the built-in tools:

- Multi-camera mode could work if each camera would have cuts at the same points. However, this is not the case.
- Merging only works for exactly one video clip and audio.
- I also tried to arrange the videos and the audio on a timeline and apply synchronize for each video/audio combination. However, it moves the audio, not the video, therefore it doesn't work either.

Is there any trick to make this work? I need separate tracks per camera because the cameras are very different and need to be color corrected individually.

Comment: Cuts don't need to be in the same place for Multi-camera mode to work.  Does each camera recording have the same audio on it?

Comment: Each clip has the audio from the build-in microphone.

Comment: If you can hear what they are saying on the built-in mic, Premiere is usually pretty good about syncing them up using Multi-camera mode.

Comment: But then how would I go from multi-camera mode to having all clips of a camera on one track (for the color correction part)?

Comment: When you add your multi-camera sequence to a normal sequence, it appears as a single track in the normal sequence.  You then cut between the different cameras.  You can apply colour correction per clip, or to all the source clips - the links in the answer below should explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is audible speech of the event on the built-in microphone of each camera, Premiere is usually pretty good about syncing them up.

I would throw all the clips into a multi-camera sequence, set to sync using audio.  Set whichever camera is the best one to be the main sequence settings, then let it do its thing.

You will end up with a tonne of video tracks and a tonne of audio tracks, but from that point onwards, it's just shuffling the clips around in a game of video-Tetris until you have the right clips on the right tracks.  The syncing is the time consuming bit, and hopefully Premiere will do that part for you.

Make the multi camera sequence using Audio to sync.
When it is done, duplicate the sequence, and work from the duplicate.

Right click the multi-camera sequence and select "open in timeline"

Move all the camera 1 clips to Layer 1, Camera 2 clips to layer 2 etc.

When this is done, make a new "normal" sequence, and drag your multi-camera sequence into it.

You should now be able to cut between cameras [using the multi-camera tools](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/create-multi-camera-source-sequence.html) in Premiere (make a cut, right click, select which camera you want for each
clip).  There are shortcuts to make this faster.

I often end up adding the master audio to the normal sequence after I've put the multicamera sequence in, because the multi-camera tool often messes with the audio panning per clip.

You can colour correct afterwards using [source clip effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/premiere-pro/using/master-clip-effects.html) per camera, or on a clip by clip basis, or you can apply them within the multi-camera sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tomh's answer which is correct:

In my case, it could happen that at certain times there was only one camera filming at a time. In this case, the multi-camera sequence could not be generated as there was no way to determine where to add a certain clip.

As I mentioned in the initial question, the only thing I have at full length is the audio track. However, you (naturally) cannot use audio files for creating a multi-camera sequence. I circumvented this by creating a video of my audio track with just a black background using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=5 -i input.mp3 -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

[Source](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/29547/36664)

As a consequence, I could use this clip for creating a multi-camera sequence and it combined all videos correctly.

Comment: Off topic but I have to say it, genius!